# how we post value from one page to another page using php

Tags: php, html

```
        <form name="frm1" method="post" action="/123/123/123/123/result_page.php">
        <td class="search_bar"><input type="text" name="textfield"  style="width:95%; height:28px; border:0px;" /></td>
        <td class="search_btn"><a href="/123/123/123/123/result_page.php?searchCity=<?php $_POST['textfield'] ?>"></a></td>
        </form>
```

Comment: What is the question where is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Add a submit button to your form:

```
<form name="frm1" method="post" action="/123/123/123/123/result_page.php">
  <td class="search_bar">
    <input type="text" name="searchCity" />
  </td>
  <td class="search_btn">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </td>
</form>
```

Having a link as you have will bypass the form and generate a GET request, not a POST.

Comment: @Shakti Singh : sorry if u have problem in understanding the question. actually i have search bar and i want to post it values to  result_page.php when user click on search button.